# c# how to clone picture box 1 into pb 2?

Tags: c#, picturebox, display

I use two functions to load live camera and picture into picture box 1 and I want the same to be displayed in picture box2 also...

whatever comes in pb1 should also come in pb2.

Comment: Can't you just create a function like `SetImage(...)`, that just sets the image to whatever box you want, instead of assigning the new image directly to an individual box in your other functions? Least overhead and simple implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `PictureBox` does not have `event` like `OnImageChanged`, so you got to work around with it.

One way to work around with it is by creating your own `MyPictureBox` class derived from `PictureBox` (winform) in which it has its own (overshadowing) `Image` property. Then in the class you declare `ImageChanged` event and well as its handler. Then, in the `setter` of the `Image` property, you could call `ImageChanged` event.

When the `ImageChanged` occurs, you can change the other `PictureBox` image too.

Alternatively, you may want to make use of the existing (similar) `LoadCompleted` event of the `PictureBox` and then triggers the other `PictureBox` to get the new image.

See if any method may work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Hi @user3004860 in my sample , I have quietly insert picture to the file folder when I put a picture in the box , so that you can use it in anywhere ,hopefully my idea can help you to deal with your question , as following code is the sample

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileExt))
            {
                var strExt = fileExt.ToLower();
                var newFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"), Random.Next(0, 9999).ToString("D4"), strExt);
                var newOFileName = "o" + newFileName;                  

                string imgUrl = "/Files";

                var directory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~"+imgUrl));
                if (!directory.Exists)
                    directory.Create();

                try
                {

                    upload.SaveAs(directory + "/" + newOFileName);
                    string res;                    
                        res =
                            string.Format(
                                "top.$('.mce-btn.mce-open').parent().find('.mce-textbox').val('{0}{1}').closest('.mce-window').find('.mce-primary').click();",
                                imgUrl + '/', newOFileName);
                    return Content(res);
                }
                catch
                {
                    return Content("error");
                }

            }
```